# Substitution in multiple variables along a square

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate $\iint_R(x^2-y^2)e^{(x+y)^2}\text{d}x\text{d}y$ Where R is the region in the xy plane bounded by the square with vertices $(0,1),(1,2),(2,1),(1,0)$ Make the substitution $u=x+y \text{ and } v=x-y$ and rewrite the integral. I got $\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{1}^{3}\frac{uve^{v^2}}{2}\text{d}u\text{d}v$ however that is incorrect. Can someone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: The region R, as given, is not a square.
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(0,0),(1,2),(2,1),(1,0)

Comment: My bad, I typed it wrong I'll fix it